Discrepancy between HTML and displayed PDF version from html2pdf causing loss in styling
I am writing a JavaScript application for a website that takes a bunch of different inputs, runs calculations and gives an output. I am having issues with html2pdf losing styling in a very particular way. The app has very complex styling but, the pdf works with the styles for almost everything except this:
paragraph.innerHTML = `
  <strong>test text</strong> (test text test text)
    <ul>
      <li>${rangeA} to ${rangeB} mL/day</li>
      <strong>OR</strong>
      <li>${roundDownToEvenTenths(rangeA/2.0)} to ${roundDownToEvenTenths(rangeB/2.0)} mL twice a day</li>
    </ul>
  <strong>test text test text</strong> test test test
    <ul>
      <li>${rangeA} to ${rangeC} mL/day</li>
      <strong>OR</strong>
      <li>${roundDownToEvenTenths(rangeA/2.0)} to ${roundDownToEvenTenths(rangeC/2.0)} mL twice a day</li>
  </ul>`;

As you can see, I am dynamically inserting these lists into the HTML, and then later when I build the pdf, it retrieves these elements by either a class query or ID. The rest of my reports are working perfectly fine. It only seems to slightly alter the style whenever I add text after closing out a bulleted list .
In the browser it looks correctly like this:

In the PDF it displays incorrectly like this:

I have been trying to solve this issue for days now, and I am starting to think the solution is finding an alternative to html2pdf although I am trying to avoid that because I like html2pdf's simplicity.
I appreciate any help on this.

I've tried adding break elements between lists.
Turned my string into a condensed one-liner incase white space in my string was an issue.
I tried directly inserting the CSS I need into the html2pdf html itself.
Of course, I have looked through my CSS and html multiple times looking for typos and syntax errors. It seems to be free of these.

I am expecting it to not look the way it does. I dont understand why my styling works fine right up to when I try to add more text after closing a  element.

The problem is because your HTML is invalid. strong cannot be a child of an ul. Similarly, strong is an inline element, so it cannot contain block-level elements, such as ul or li - that's assuming the missing </strong> tag is intentional and not a typo. The browser will probably handle errors like that because their HTML renderers are very robust. A third-party library will not be so forgiving, so you need to make sure your HTML is completely valid. I would also assume that there are other issues in HTML that you've not shown in the question due to the layout discrepancies.

@RoryMcCrossan Thank you for informing me not to use  in this way. I will implement this and keep in mind. However, removing all  elements from my HTML doesnt fix the problem unfortunately.

@KJ That makes sense. I appreciate it. I think I ultimately may need to re-design the look of the PDF to make this work.
